# How to change on_press "animation" of Tkinter button in python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, customization

i have a taskbar-like `Frame`, which contains custom `Button`s with images. But everytime i click on this button, Tkinter displaced the button 1px to the right/buttom.

[image: Button clicked]

Is it possible to override this behaviour? Or do i have to derived from `Tkinter.Label` instead of `Tkinter.Button` ?

**edit:**
Adding some code:
    import Tkinter
    import logging

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
class DesktopBtn(Tkinter.Button):
    '''
    Represents a Button which can switch to other Desktops
    '''

    _FONTCOLOR="#FFFFFF"

    def getRelativePath(self,folder,name):
        import os
        dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir_path, '..', folder, name))

    def __init__(self, parent,desktopManager,buttonName, **options):
        '''
        :param buttonName: Name of the button

        '''
        Tkinter.Button.__init__(self, parent, **options)
        logger.info("init desktop button")
        self._imagePath=self.getRelativePath('res','button.gif')
        self._BtnPresspath = self.getRelativePath('res','buttonP.gif')
        self._BtnPressImage = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file=self._BtnPresspath)
        self._image = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file=self._imagePath)
        self.bind('<ButtonPress-1>',self._on_pressed)
        self.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',self._on_release)
        self._parent = parent
        self._btnName = buttonName
        self._desktopManager = desktopManager
        self.config(width=70, height=65,borderwidth=0,compound=Tkinter.CENTER,font=("Arial", 9,"bold"),foreground=self._FONTCOLOR, text=buttonName,wraplength=64,image=self._image, command=self._onClickSwitch)

    def _on_pressed(self,event):
        self.config(relief="flat")
        self.config(image=self._BtnPressImage)

    def _on_release(self,event):
        self.config(image=self._image)

    def _onClickSwitch(self):
        self.config(relief="flat")
        logger.info("Buttonclickmethod onClickSwitch")
        self._desktopManager.switchDesktop(self._btnName)

    def getButtonName(self):
        return self._btnName
```

Comment: Could you show some code? Have you tried a different [relief style](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/relief.html)? Have not tried with image, but `SUNKEN` button seems not to move when clicked.

Comment: Here you go. I'm using the `relief` sytle `"flat"`. I've also tried `sunken` but i didn't see any difference. When i init the `Button` with `relief="sunken"` the width space is enabled all the time. If i use `Label` the animation is gone but, i can't disable the label and the font doesn't change.

Comment: It seems you set the relief to `flat` in `on_pressed`, so you might have to remove that, too (or change it to sunken in that place, if you haven't already). But sunken will probably not look good, with that border around the button. Ugly hacky alternative: Make the "activated" image so it's shifted 1px to the top-left :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether this works with your specialized button, but how the button moves when it's clicked seems to depend on it's [relief style](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/relief.html). With `relief=SUNKEN`, the button seems not to move at all when clicked, and with `borderwidth=0` it appears to be indistinguishable from a `FLAT` button.

Minimal example:

```
root = Tk()
image = PhotoImage(file="icon.gif")
for _ in range(5):
    Button(root, image=image, borderwidth=0, relief=SUNKEN).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Note that you set and re-set the `relief` to `FLAT` multiple times in your code, so you might have to change them all for this to take effect.

Comment: I've already tried this approach, this only works if u have the default backgroundcolor. If you change for example, the root-background to black  ( `root.config(background="black")`) and the button-background to black (`Button(root,background="black",...)`) it seems to work, but only to the point till you click on the Button, where the backgroundcolor will turn to default again.

Comment: @VRage Have you tried also setting `activebackground="black"` in the Buttons?

Comment: No i didn't and this actually works. Vielen Dank. Somehow i've overlooked this option in the documentation. Can you please add those options to your examplecode.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the animation of a button by returning "break" in the widget's  bind, which stops the propagation of bound functions.

So you can either alter the function you normally have bound to the button to return "break".

Or you can add another bind, this does however prevent any binds that are made after this one:

```
tkButton.bind("<Button-1>", lambda _: "break", add=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found some kind of a solution using relief and border:

```
closebut = Button(title, text="X", relief=SUNKEN, bd=0, command=close)
closebut.pack(side=RIGHT)
```

You can observe that I used `relief = SUNKEN` and then `bd = 0` to get a nice FLAT effect on my button!