# Disable pressed button effect TKINTER

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I am making a GUI with `tkinter` and I want to disable pressed button effect. Pressed button moves a small to left corner and make white "border". How to disable this? Picture.jpg is only illustration. Thanks

CODE:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
window = Tk()
window.geometry("900x500")
window.configure(bg = "#00B2FF")
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('TButton', background = "#00B2FF")

Submit_icon = PhotoImage(file = r"picture.jpg")
Submit_Button = Button(window,image = Submit_icon, bd = 0, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness = 0,highlightcolor= "#00B2FF", relief = "flat", activeforeground="#00B2FF")
Submit_Button.pack(pady=10)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can use a label to simulate a button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change on\_press "animation" of Tkinter button in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30915213/how-to-change-on-press-animation-of-tkinter-button-in-python)

Comment: Ok thanks i think labels will be fine